# Variable substitution for double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, area

I'm calculating the following integral:

$$I=\iint_{D}2cos((x+y)^2)\, dxdy,$$
where $D=\left \{ (x,y):1 \leq x+y \leq 3, x \geq 0, y \geq 0 \right \}$.

To get around the fact that I would have to divide this area into two integrals I'm trying to find a clever variable substitution. It seems obvious that one of them, say $u$, should be $u=x+y$. I'm not sure what the other could be. I'm thinking about something like $v=x-y$, which would be the orthogonal line to $u=x+y$, which would (to me) be possible. Can you find some better and more effective variable substitution? I'm not very experienced so could you maybe give me some tips when it comes to variable substitutions like these?

I would be thankful!

Comment: $u=x+y, v=x$ should work fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yeah that works! The boundaries for u would be $1\leq u\leq 3$ but what would the boundaries for v be? I guess the lower bound should be 0, but the upper would be some kind of line right?

Comment: Yes. Draw a picture. The region is made up of  a triangle and a  rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, $u = x + y, v = x~$ (or $~v = y$) would work.

$|J| = 1$

Bounds of $u$ is $1 \leq u \leq 3$ as you mentioned. For bounds of $v$, note that $x, y \geq 0$. So, $v = x \geq 0$ and $v \leq u$ ( as, $x \leq x + y, ~$ given $x, y \geq 0$)

This change of variables simplifies the integral.